# Validation of only one form

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

On a page with two forms I need a script that will validate only the one that is being submitted. 
I have made a simple page that shows the problem

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function validateForm() {
var checks = document.getElementsByName("tjek");
var checksChecked = false;

var i = 0;
while (!checksChecked && i < checks.length) {
    if (checks[i].checked) checksChecked = true;
    i++;
}


if (!checksChecked) {
    alert("Select something!")
    return false;
}
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form onSubmit='return validateForm()' action="" method="get">
<input name="tjek" type="checkbox" value="" />
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
<form onSubmit='return validateForm()' action="" method="get">
<input name="tjek" type="checkbox" value="" />
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/duqotobi/1/edit

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? You should also make a live demo on e.g. http://jsbin.com/. And add a doctype.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'doesn't work'?

Comment: I submitting the first form and the checkbox isn't checked, it gives me an alert like it should. But if the checkbox in the second form is checked, it will not give an alert. So for some reason the script reads all checkboxes. Not just those inside the form being submitted.

Comment: `"But if the checkbox in the second form is checked, it will not give an alert."` Why should it? The functions sees whether checkboxes are *not* checked, and only then throws an alert. Maybe you should describe step by step what it is exactly that you expect from the code.

Comment: What I ment was, If the checkbox in the second form is checked and the first form is submitted, it will not give an alert. What I want is that the script only checks on the checkbox inside the form being submitted.

Comment: OK, got it. Let me fiddle a bit.

Comment: I gave you a working solution 3 hours ago, but no response. Please tell me this is not an ordinary homework assignment? At least have the decency to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes: live demo: http://jsbin.com/duqotobi/2/edit?html,output.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Demo</title>
<script>
function validateForm(caller) {
    var checks = caller.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i=0; i<checks.length; i++) {
        if (checks[i].checked == false) {
            alert("Select something.");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            caller.submit();
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="firstForm" action="form_handler.php" method="get">
        <input name="tjek" type="checkbox" value="" />
        <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="validateForm(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>

    <form name="secondForm" action="form_handler.php" method="get">
        <input name="tjek" type="checkbox" value="" />
        <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="validateForm(this.parentNode)"  />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If it's not fully self-explanatory, let me know. Do realize however, that it is tricky to give checkboxes the same names, even if it concerns different forms. Only radio inputs belonging to the same group should have the same name. This script is not critical in that aspect, but just so you know.

I rewrote it in my style of JS validation scripting; other styles are possible as well.

Comment: It is working like I wanted. Really great. I may switch over to radios to be safe.
I tried this code on the group of radios I have on the same page and in the same forms as the checkboxes. They have three radios in each group. Tried the script on them and it cant handle them, sadly. But these chekcboxes are the most important to have validated.

Comment: You'd have a new question for that, otherwise readers cannot follow the thread anymore. But I would also suggest to do some internet searching before you ask a new question. In the meantime, please accept this answer (click the V/tick sign next to it), since it works for the current question.